# Infinite random stream

Tags: random, stream, scheme, racket, r5rs

I'm having some trouble creating an infinite random stream of numbers from 0 to 9.
Here's where I'm at now:

```
(#%require (only mzscheme random))
(define (input_stream) (cons (random 9) (delay input_stream)))
```

Only problem is, `(random 9)` appears to be initiated only once. The stream is indeed random, but the values of the stream remain constant.

I get `7, 7, 7, 7, 7` or `3, 3, 3, 3, 3`

Any ideas on how to initiate the random function each time the endless loop starts over?
I've searched all over online, but couldn't find any way to tackle this one.

Comment: By the way, you appear to be using `#%require` and the deprecated `mzscheme` library. It is probably much easier if you use `#lang racket` (which has, e.g., `random` built-in).

Comment: Thank you for bringing it to my attention

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it is, the `random` procedure is called only once because you didn't recursively  call `input_stream` again, that's why all the random numbers in the stream are in fact, the same number. You have to guarantee that the pseudo-random number generator is called every time a new value is `cons`'ed, for example:

```
(define (random-stream n)
  (cons (random n) (delay (random-stream n))))
```

Now this stream will contain random numbers in the range 0-9:

```
(define input_stream (random-stream 10))
```

Note: I defined `n` as a parameter jut to make the generated stream parameterizable, it'll work just as well with a fixed value:

```
(define (random-stream)
  (cons (random 10) (delay (random-stream))))

(define input_stream (random-stream))
```

For example, to access the first three elements:

```
(car input_stream)
=> 9 ; random number between 0-9
(car (force (cdr input_stream)))
=> 7 ; random number between 0-9
(car (force (cdr (force (cdr input_stream)))))
=> 8 ; random number between 0-9
```

Or in general, for generating a list of `m` random elements from 0 (inclusive) to `n` (exclusive):

```
(define (stream-take s m)
  (if (zero? m)
      '()
      (cons (car s)
            (stream-take (force (cdr s)) (sub1 m)))))

(stream-take (random-stream 10) 20)           ; n=10, m=20
=> '(3 3 3 7 0 7 3 2 3 7 6 0 6 4 1 4 6 1 6 9) ; 20 random numbers between 0-9
```

Comment: Any way I can print the first few numbers?
In the original code I can see the first number with (input_stream), but in your code I get an error that it's not a procedure...

I'm sure these are obvious questions, sorry about that I'm quite novice when it comes to scheme.

Comment: See my updated answer. Notice that this is a _from-scratch_ implementation of streams, in Racket there are built-in primitives for this, for example `stream-cons`

Comment: Great! thank you for your help. Hopefully I'll be able to implement the infinite stream with an encoder.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure how much sense it makes to create a random stream, since simply calling (random n) repeatedly will achieve the same effect.

But a nice way to create streams is with *stream-cons*:

```
#lang racket

;;; infinite stream of random numbers
(define (random-stream n)
  (stream-cons 
   (random n) 
   (random-stream n)))
```

It is important how you consume streams, since you might end up getting the first number every time if you do it wrong:

```
(define S (random-stream 10))

;;; right 
(for/list ((i (range 5)))
  (stream-ref S i))
=> '(7 1 4 8 4)

;;; right
; primitive to take the first n elements of a stream
(define (stream-take s n)
  (for/list ((e s) (i (in-range n)))
    e))
(stream-take S 20)  
=> '(7 1 4 8 4 3 9 8 6 8 4 8 1 1 1 7 0 3 9 4)

;;; wrong
(for/list ((i (range 5)))
  (stream-take S 1))
=> '((7) (7) (7) (7) (7))
```